# What is the laravel way of storing API keys?

Tags: security, laravel

Is there a specific file or directory that is recommended for storing API keys? I'd like to take my keys out of my codebase but I'm not sure where to put them.

Comment: My first thought was the /app/config/ directory, but that would be submitted to version control, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your API keys environment variables and then access them that way. Read more about [protecting sensitive configuration from the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#protecting-sensitive-configuration).

You simply create a `.env.php` file in the root of your project that returns an array of environment variables.

```
<?php

return array(
    'SECRET_API_KEY' => 'PUT YOUR API KEY HERE'
);
```

Then you can access it in your app like so.

```
getenv('SECRET_API_KEY');
```

Comment: Thanks! Are .env.php files automatically ingnored by git?

Comment: The current version of Laravel does ignore them by default but I'm not sure when this was introduced. If you started your project recently then they should be, otherwise you can add it to the `.gitignore` yourself. You can look at the `.gitignore` in the Laravel repo as a reference.

Answer (score 30):

This is an updated answer for newer versions of Laravel.

First, set the credentials in your `.env` file. Generally you'll want to prefix it with the name of the service, so in this example I'll use Google Maps.

```
GOOGLE_KEY=secret_api_key
```

Then, take a look in `config/services.php` - it's where we can map environment variables into the app configuration. You'll see some existing examples out of the box. You can add additional configuration under the service name and point it to the environment variable.

```
'google' => [
    'key' => env('GOOGLE_KEY'),
],
```

Then when you need to access this key within your app you can get it through the app configuration instead.

```
// Through a facade
Config::get('services.google.key');

// Through a helper
config('services.google.key');
```

Be sure *not* to just use `env('GOOGLE_KEY)` through your app - it's more performant to go through the app configuration as it's cached - especially if you call `php artisan config:cache` as part of your deployment process.

Comment: Excellent answer @Dwight.